# Why is my probability value greater than 1?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

**Question** Given the observation $\{H,T,H,H,T\}$, use the Bayes rule to find the probability that the coin is unbased?

**My approach** Let the probability of seeing heads be $f$. For unbiased coin, $f=.5$. Using Bayes rule,

$$
\Pr[.5|\{H,T,H,H,T\}] = \frac{\Pr[\{H,T,H,H,T\}|.5]\Pr[.5]}{\int_0^1\Pr[.5]\Pr[\{H,T,H,H,T\}|f]df}
$$

$\Pr[.5]$ is independent of $f$, it can be brought out of the integral and since it is present in both numerator and denominator, it can also be ignored. As tossing a coin is a Bernoulli trial, the probability is given as,
$$
\Pr[\{H,T,H,H,T\}|f] = \bigg(\begin{matrix}5 \\ 3\end{matrix}\bigg)f^3 (1-f)^2
$$
Substituting the above expression,

$$
\Pr[.5|\{H,T,H,H,T\}] = \frac{\bigg(\begin{matrix}5 \\ 3\end{matrix}\bigg).5^3 .5^2}{\int_0^1\bigg(\begin{matrix}5 \\ 3\end{matrix}\bigg)f^3 (1-f)^2df} = \frac{1/2^5}{1/60} = \frac{60}{32} > 1
$$
The binomial is present in numerator and denominator and can be ignored. The integral without the binomial co-efficiant is Beta function $B(4,3)=1/60$. Clearly I have made some mistake and I cannot figure out where.

What is the mistake in my approach? And what would be the correct approach to the problem? Thank you.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you assuming that, a priori,  the true probability is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$?  But then the answer is obviously $0$ since the probability that a continuously uniform distribution takes a particular value is $0$.

Comment: As for a correct *problem*, one that is answerable but still related to the current problem... "Suppose we have a bag with two coins in it.  The one coin is fair and the other is biased with probability of heads being $0.6$.  Supposing we blindly reach into the bag and take one of these coins at random and flip it five times and we happen to have gotten the sequence HTHHT, what is the probability that it was the fair coin that we had selected?"  Here we'd have a discrete selection of the coin's distribution.

Comment: Why is my problem incorrect and not answerable, @JMoravitz?

Comment: Your question is answerable, it's just not interesting.  The answer is $0$.  Your calculation is wrong because your numerator is wrong.  Your numerator should be $0$ since the probability that the true probability is exactly $.5$ is $0$, not what you wrote.

Comment: Assuming a continuous prior, you could ask about an interval.  "What's the posteriori probability that the true probability is between $.49$ and $.51$?" works, for instance.

Comment: @lulu so you are saying that if I use a continuous prior, then all my probabilities should be in the form $Pr[a<f<b]$? like the density functions where the probability of any particular value is zero?

Comment: If you want to get a sensible answer, yes.  For a continuous distribution, asking about exact values doesn't mean much.  Should say:  nowhere in your post do you specify that you are assuming a continuous prior.  I am just guessing that from your integral.

Comment: Yes. I am assuming a uniform $B(1,1)$ prior. So, will it be wrong to write something like, $\Pr[f|HTHHT]=60f^3(1-f)^2$, @lulu?

Comment: Of course that's wrong (again, assuming you have a continuous prior).  That's more of a density, not a probability.